# Associate two MySQL rows

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit confusing. I cant find how to word it for google and I just cant wrap my head around the logic to do this.
I have "contacts" and "sites" tables that I am storing data for in a database. We need to have a page showing the contacts information and what "sites" they are associated with AND have a page for information about a "site" and show what contacts are associated with it. 
Right now I have a field for "contacts" that has comma separated ids of each site that its associated with and a field for "sites" that also has comma separated ids of each contact associated with that site.

When I create a new site with an associated contact. how should the logic go that will update the "associated sites" field on the contacts row in MySQL while also updating its own "associated contacts" field?

Comment: If you could define your tables' schema, someone could probably help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are speaking about many-to-many relationships.

I assume you have a table design like this:

```
tbl_contacts                tbl_sites
id | full_name              id | label
 1 | John Doe                1 | my website
 3 | Maria Doe               2 | super website
```

You need a table to "link" the tables. this is a many-to-many-table:

```
tbl_contacts2sites
id | contact_id | site_id
 1 |          1 |       2
 5 |          1 |       1
 3 |          3 |       2
```

So, John Doe is assigned to both sites, but Maria only to the "super site".
This is the common way to design your relationships. You should avoid any comma seperated lists for this kind of relationships.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've seen this done before but never really understood the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be when you create a third table (contacts2sites) in this table you have three columns called: id, siteid, contactid.

In this table you can add every connection between sites and contacts. To query the data out of it you can use the mysql query with joins over all tables.

little example:
[solution with joins](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a311b/1)